# Symfony form errors

Tags: symfony

I have 3 Entity Client, Classes, Fournitures. Client has an OnetoMany relations with Fournitures and Fourniteurs has a ManytoOne relations with Classes, to do this I make a nest fields for the Client form as here is the ClientType:

```
$builder->add('nom')
    ->add('adresse')
    ->add('idfournitures', FournituresType::class);
```

FournituresType

```
$builder->add('nom')
    ->add('value')
    ->add('prix')
    ->add('idclasses', ClassesType::class);
```

ClassesType

```
$builder->add('categories')
    ->add('famille');
```

the form is fine but the problem now is that during my newAction, it returns the error : `A new entity was found through the relationship 'AppBundle\Entity\Fournitures#idclasses' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}).`

and although i have already set up my entity Classes with cascade persist in Fournitures and also persisted in my newAction, the problem still persists.

```
/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Classes
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Classes", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idclasses", referencedColumnName="idclasses", nullable=false)
 * })
 */
private $idclasses;
```

NewAction

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $em->persist($client);
        $em->persist($client->getIdfournitures());
        $em->persist($client->getIdfournitures()->getIdclasses());
        $em->flush();

        }
```

I do not know if what I'm doing this with symfony or not, but I need help to solve the problem because I do not know what to do, thank you!

Comment: Can you post your entire newAction()

Answer (score 0):

Add cascade persist to your oneToMany relation too.